# Is there a name for raising a number to its own value as a power

Tags: terminology, exponentiation

Is there a mathematical term for raising a a number to the power of its own value....
eg. $5^5 , 1692^{1692}$.

Many Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is of interest to you.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's worth noting that there is a mathematical (and specifically combinatorial) _interpretation_ for the quantity $n^n$; it's precisely the number of functions from a $n$-element set to itself.  This can be broken down based on how many different values the function takes on (for instance, those functions with $n$ different values are precisely the permutations), leading into the theory of set partitions.

Comment: Indeed, the number of endofunctions on an n-element set, https://oeis.org/A000312

Answer (score 7):

Adding a number to itself is a form of multiplication: $x + x = 2x$. Multiplying a number by itself is a form of exponentiation: $x\cdot x = x^2$. Raising a number to its own power is a form of tetration: $x^x = x\uparrow\uparrow2$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Answer (score 0):

Both addition, multiplication, exponentiation and the operation you are describing are  particular cases of the following recursive function $H: \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ (called "hyperoperation"):

$$H(n, a, b)= \begin{cases}b+1 & \quad n=0 \\ a & \quad n = 1 \\ 0 & \quad n = 2, b = 0 \\ 1 & \quad n \geq 3, b = 0 \\ H(n-1,a, H(n,a,b-1)) \end{cases}$$

It is not hard to see, that

$$H(1, a, b) = a + b$$

$$H(2, a, b) = ab$$

$$H(3, a, b) = a^b$$

and $H(4, a, b)$ is the exact binary operation on $a$ and $b$ of iterated exponentiation. That is the reason, why that operation is called "tetration" (from the Greek word "τέταρτος", which means "fourth").

So $a^a = H(4, a, 2)$ is the thing you were most likely looking for.